# Add parentheses around text in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file set up like this:

| var | all | some | never | pvalue | stat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| white | .45 | .42 | .33 | .01 | mean |
| white | .02 | .01 | .03 |  | se |
| black | .25 | .13 | .21 | .13 | mean |
| black | .02 | .04 | .02 |  | se |

Basically, every other row is a mean and a standard error for different demographics, and broken down by column for various groups in my dataset (plus pvalue for differences between two of those groups).

I want to add a () around the SEs. Is there a way to do this systematically in Excel (or Word, which is where I'm copying it over to eventually)?

EDIT: Adding what I meant more clearly, the final product would look like this:

| var | all | some | never | pvalue | stat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| white | .45 | .42 | .33 | .01 | mean |
| white | (.02) | (.01) | (.03) |  | se |
| black | .25 | .13 | .21 | .13 | mean |
| black | (.02) | (.04) | (.02) |  | se |

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "SEs".

Comment: Just use Replace

Comment: Sorry--I meant around the rows of numbers that are SEs. I can edit the original post to be more clear.

Comment: To do this in place you will need vba.

Comment: If VBA is not an option, then considering replicating your sheet where the data are all populated with an "IF" formula. Something like =if($F2="se",concat("(",sheet1!B2,")"),"sheet1!B2)